# recursive function to get all equivalents product using php

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.3

I am using symfony 3 and I have table piece with Many-To-Many relation Self-referencing .
One Piece have many equivalents pieces.
an equivalent piece is associated to many piece.

For example :

pieces      :       **piece 1  |   piece 2  | piece 3**

equivalents :       **piece 4  |   piece 1   | piece 4
                                             piece 5**

I want to get all equivalents for piece 1 the result must be : **piece 4 , piece 2 , piece 3 , piece 5**

Here is the code that I tried , it give just  : piece 4 , piece 3

```
 public function findAllEquivalentsByReference($reference)
{
    $pieceFinales = array();
    $listFinal = array();

    $pieceO =  $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
             'SELECT p FROM EKPlateformeBundle:Piece p '.
             'where  p.reference = :ref   and  p.etat = true ')
        ->setParameter('ref',$reference)
        ->getResult();

    if (empty($pieceO))
    {
          $pieceO =  $this->getEntityManager()
        ->createQuery(
             'SELECT p FROM EKPlateformeBundle:Piece p '.
             'INNER JOIN p.references_oem  r '.
             'where (( r.reference = :ref ) OR ( p.reference = :ref  ) ) and 
             ( p.etat = true )')
        ->setParameter('ref',$reference)
        ->getResult();
    }


     foreach ($pieceO as $piece) 
     {      
            $equivalents = $piece->getEquivalents();
            $initiaux = $piece->getPieceInitiale(); 

            // Les equivalents : 
            foreach ($equivalents as $pe)
            {   
                    $autreEquivalents = $pe->getEquivalents();
                    array_push($listFinal, $pe); 
                    foreach ($autreEquivalents as $p)
                    {  
                        if (!in_array($p, $listFinal))
                        {
                            array_push($listFinal, $p);
                            $piece->addEquivalent($p);
                        }
                    }
            }

            //
            foreach ($initiaux as $i)
            {   
                $autreInitiaux = $i->getPieceInitiale();
                array_push($listFinal, $i);
                $piece->addEquivalent($i);
                foreach ($autreInitiaux as $pii)
                {  
                       if (!in_array($pii, $listFinal))
                       {
                          array_push($listFinal, $pii);
                          $piece->addEquivalent($pii);
                       }
                }
            }
            array_push($pieceFinales ,$piece);
    }
    return $pieceFinales ;  
}
```

I could'nt find a recursive function to give the correct result.

Comment: What have you tried? What you have posted is not used as a recursive function.

Comment: I tried to replace this code by recursive function but i could'nt :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recursion you can't just have 1 function, you need at least 2

Example:

```
public function getEquivalentsByReference($reference)
{

    $products = $someModel->getProductsByReference($reference);
    $this->_getRecursiveEquivalents($products);
    return $products;

}

protected function _getRecursiveEquivalents(&$products)
{
    $equivalents = [];
    foreach($products as $product) {
        $equivalents[] = $someModel->getReferencesByID($product->reference);
    }
    $this->_getRecursiveEquivalents($equivalents);
    $products = array_merge($products, $equivalents)


}
```

Comment: thank you , your answer help me to find the solution , thank you very much :) :D

Comment: yw, accept it if you please, the question was quiet localized anyway